# SQL - Count occurences of distinct values in column

Tags: sql, postgresql

To make long story short:

I have table like this

```
nr   sat   col
1    1     dsag
1    2     gds
1    2     gds
2    1     gdsa
2    2     gf
2    3     gdsa
```

And expect the result like this:

```
nr  Sat_1   Sat_2   Sat_3
1   1       2       0
2   1       1       1
```

I want new column for each row from "SELECT DISTINCT sat" and next group by nr

Comment: "Long story short" - you'll need to use a `COUNT(DISTINCT col)` with `GROUP BY nr, sat` to get the numbers, and a `PIVOT` to get your desired display.  To make this short story longer, please show what you've tried already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like a_horse_with_no_name's answer.  This is shorter, although it might be slightly slower:

```
select nr, 
       sum((sat = 1)::int) as sat_1, 
       sum((sat = 2)::int) as sat_2, 
       sum((sat = 3)::int) as sat_3
from the_table
group by nr
order by nr;
```

The more typical way to write the query is using `case`:

```
select nr, 
       sum(case when sat = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as sat_1, 
       . . .
```

This happens to be standard SQL that will run in many databases.

Comment: The `filter()` clause is standard SQL as well ;)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Is there some place with a chart of standard sql features and which rdbms support it? e.g. like you can find for emca5/6 and browsers ? https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: Not really, I guess because the SQL standard is not available for free. The only remotely similar comparison I know is: http://www.sql-workbench.net/dbms_comparison.html but that is far from being complete, nor is it limited to features from the SQL standard.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 6):

This can be done using conditional aggregation:

```
select nr, 
       count(*) filter (where sat = 1) as sat_1, 
       count(*) filter (where sat = 2) as sat_2, 
       count(*) filter (where sat = 3) as sat_3
from the_table
group by nr
order by nr;
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/YVIR75756

Comment: Yes, I know but I don't want to do it manually because there are much more values in sat column than in this example. It would be perfect if it will create "count line" automatically for each distinct value

Comment: @dekarz: you should  have mentioned that in your question. But in general that's not possible. The number of columns of a query must be known to the database _before_ it is executed.

Comment: I see. Thank you anyway, it seems to be the best answer ! :) But I'm disappointed that I can't do it as i imagined.

Comment: According to [modern sql](http://modern-sql.com/feature/filter), `filter` is part of the **optional** "Advanced OLAP operations". Does it qualify as standard?

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis . . . If it is in the standard as an optional feature, then it is standard.  As with some other things in the standard, Postgres may be the only database (if any) that supports them.

Comment: @GordonLinoff HSQLDB also supports the `filter` clause